# Filter records yearly, monthly quarterly or weekly

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a requirement to write a SQL to filter out records based on a date type column.

| Product(VARCHAR2) | Created Date (Date) | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3/5/2021 12:20:15 PM | 20 |
| B | 3/5/2021 12:20:15 PM | 30 |

Filtering should be done annually, monthly, quarterly or weekly ( based on the user input) using the "Created Date" column.

Example User Inputs;

Ex 01:

Year: 2020, Quarter: 1 ( possible values 1,2,3,4)

Ex: 02

Year: 2020, Month : 6, Week: 1 ( possible values 1,2,3,4)

Ex: 03

Year: 2020, Month : 6

Ex: 04

Year: 2020

How can this be achieved using Oracle SQL?

Thanks!

Cheers, Nuwan

Comment: On a side note: If week is the month's week, then possible values of 1 to 4 cover the first 28 days only (provided week #1 means days 1 to 7 etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Look at it like this; there are four criteria the user can request:

- year
- quarter
- month
- week

The year is obligatory, the others are optional. The task is to check which criteria are given and use or not use them in the query (e.g. `where (:month is null or extract(month from created_date) = :month)`).

The query:

```
select *
from mytable
where extract(year from created_date) = :year
and (:quarter is null or to_number(to_char(created_date, 'q')) = :quarter)
and (:month is null or extract(month from created_date) = :month)
and (:week is null or trunc(extract(day from created_date) / 7) + 1 = :week)
```